# "Could not compute standard errors" and "The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters does not appear to be positive definite!"

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I've been stuck on this assignment for days. Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I've included a picture of the path diagram and labels for each step to make my thought process clear. I'm new to SEM and the model would be [the presented here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd3Gh.png).

First, I conducted the multiple group assessment:

```
mod.mg1a = "

#Variances

crit ~~ crit
warm ~~ warm

trust ~~ trust

never ~~ never
moral ~~ moral
han ~~ han
good ~~ good

#Regression/Causal Path

trust ~ warm
trust ~ crit

#Factor Loadings

trust =~ never + moral + han + good

"
fit.mg1a = lavaan(mod.mg1a,data=mach,group="gen")
summary(fit.mg1a)

mod.mg1b = "
#Variances

crit ~~ crit
warm ~~ warm

trust ~~ trust

never ~~ never
moral ~~ moral
han ~~ han
good ~~ good

#Regression/Causal Path

trust ~ warm
trust ~ crit

#Factor Loadings

trust =~ never + moral + han + good

"
fit.mg1b = lavaan(mod.mg1b,data=mach,group="gen")
summary(fit.mg1b)

anova(fit.mg1a, fit.mg1b)
```

This return the following warnings:

> ```
> ***Warning in lav_partable_check(lavpartable, categorical = lavoptions$categorical,  :
>   lavaan WARNING: automatically added intercepts are set to zero:
>     [warm crit warm crit]
> Warning in lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
>   lavaan WARNING:
>     Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
>     not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
>     identified.***
>
> ----------
>
> ***Warning in lavTestLRT(object = object, ..., model.names = NAMES) :
>   lavaan WARNING: some models have the same degrees of freedom***
> ```

The following assess the comparison with the model with all parameters constrained to be equal:

```
    fit.con = lavaan(mod.mg1a,data=mach, group="gen", group.equal=c(
      "loadings","lv.covariances","intercepts","means","residuals",
      "lv.variances","regressions"))
```

which returns:

> ```
> ***Warning in lav_partable_check(lavpartable, categorical = lavoptions$categorical,  :
>   lavaan WARNING: automatically added intercepts are set to zero:
>     [warm crit warm crit]
> Warning in lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
>   lavaan WARNING:
>     The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
>     does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
>     (= 7.438519e-15) is close to zero. This may be a symptom that the
>     model is not identified.***
> ```

Grateful for any guidance.